# Knockout event binding unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, events, knockout.js

I have an event binding for the `scroll` event on a DIV. For debouncing the handler I introduced a function on my model which creates the debounced handler, and I'm binding this factory function in my view.

I would expect that my factory creates the debounced function and knockout will bind that to the event. Instead, it seems like knockout recreates and calls my debounced function at every event trigger, so debouncing doesn't work at all.

My view

```
<div data-bind="event.scroll: getScrollHandler()"></div>
```

My model

```
var viewModel = {
  getScrollHandler: function(data, evt) {
    return debounceFunction(function(data, evt) {
      // dp the actual handling...
    });
  }
};
```

I would expect that the `getScrollHandler` method would execute only once at binding initialization time, and it would bind the returned function.

Instead, it seems like knockout is wrapping it all to a new function so it runs on every scroll event.

How exactly does it work in Knockout?

**UPDATE**

As I'm using TypeScript and this handler is a member method of a class, I'm limited to this kind of function member assignment, I cannot directly assign the debounced function as a member (or actually I could, but in some uglier way only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an implementation [similar to this one](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function), the idea is it creates a new function which you then use in place of your original function. Try changing your code to this:

```
getScrollHandler: debounceFunction(function(data, event) { 
  ...
})
```

This will create the function once and re-use it every time the scroll is activated.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The implementation is exactly the same, and I know what it does. However while I'm using TypeScript I'm not able to do this type of function assignment syntax, hence I created that factory method. I still don't understand why knockout works like this.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in my post, sorry. What I don't understand is how knockout works this way as I posted.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Knockout works just like anything else. If you hand it a function, it will call that function. Since you bind `getScrollHandler` and it returns a new function, it will always return a new function. That new function doesn't replace `getScrollHandler`. You could make `getScrollHandler` be an IIFE (`getScrollHandler: function(data, event) { ... }()`) and that would work since it would bind the new function to `getScrollHandler`.

Comment: Please note that I'm actually **calling** the `getScrollHandler` function in the binding, so I'm not intended to pass the `getScrollHandler` function, but its result (the debounced function). Or do I misunderstand something about it?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Knockout is kind of wonky. It will take `getScrollHandler` as an immediate binding or `getScrollHandler()` as an expression to run each time, which means they do the same thing. You'll need to change the value of `getScrollHandler` in your JS code to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: But actually when I would write `someFunction.bind($data)` or so, knockout doesn't treat it as an expression but correctly uses the returned bound function. Because of this, I assumed that I can use other expressions (like `bind`) returning a function too. What is the difference here?

Comment: @ZoltánTamási I couldn't tell you, you'd have to dig in to how Knockout handles expressions. All I know is your problem will definitely go away if you just re-assign the value of `getScrollHandler` to the return of `debounceFunction`.

Comment: Yes but as I wrote, I cannot do that as simply because of TypeScript classes and methods syntax :) Thanks anyway, I'll upvote you and also accpet it if no better answer appears, because I didn't specifically mentioned TypeScript limitations in my post.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási Based on my very limited knowledge of Typescript, I believe you can replace the handler in a class. `class ViewModel { scrollHandler() { // do stuff } }` `ViewModel.prototype.scrollHandler = debounceFunction(ViewModel.prototype.scrollHandler)`

Comment: Yep this (or something similar) is the "uglier" way which I've referred in my update.